# Как настроить логирование в maven-проекте?

Tags: java, maven

Имеется maven проект.

В pom.xml для логов:

```
<!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Во всех классах, где нужно, я включаю логирование так:

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

При сборке выдается предупреждение:

```
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar, commons-logging-1.2.jar define 19 overlapping classes: 
  - org.apache.commons.logging.LogSource
  - org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1
  - org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4
  - org.apache.commons.logging.Log
  - org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1
  - org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3
  - org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2
  - org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
  - org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException
  - org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger
  - 9 more...
maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
```

Не могу понять, о каких 2х или более JARs идет речь? И что я не так могу делать?

Comment: У вас версии не совместимы 1.1 и 1.2 (commons-logging).